# php Parse Error: Sytax error, unexpected '='

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why I am getting this error as this is the way I have always used it. Clearly I am missing something obvious, so sorry for the silly question:

Here is my code:

```
if ($ret) {
document.getElementById("updateArea").style.display = "block";
document.getElementByclass("pGroup").style.display = "block";
}
```

I don't understand. It is silly

This is in my functions file where I keep all my php functions.

Comment: this isn't php, it's javascript

Comment: Try erasing everything then typing it again. With weird key combination you can type weird characters that doesn't show but hang the compiler/interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing `PHP` with `JavaScript` and that's main problem here.

I guess that you wanted to print that two lines so your code should look like this:

```
if ($ret) {
    echo 'document.getElementById("updateArea").style.display = "block";';
    echo 'document.getElementByclass("pGroup").style.display = "block";';
}
```

And of course it should be called between `script` tags.

Comment: Remove `<br />`, they should be there, in javascript.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot. I am new to php and javascript so it is all getting a little confused.

Comment: It probably is confusing learning two languages at once! Just consider that, instead of loading an HTML file directly, you can run a PHP script instead to create HTML markup on the fly and the browser will still show that markup. In this case the HTML contains some JavaScript, between HTML <script> tags of course, which Elon's PHP is creating on the fly in just the same way.